# how to remove some fields with the WMSGetFeatureInfo function?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, geoext

I am displaying the attribute data in the popup on clicking on the map using openlayers,geoext.
But i want to hide some fields(fid,.....) from the table in the popup.
How to do this.
Below is my code

var control = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
               url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                "LAYERS": 'xxxxxx',
                  srs:'EPSG:3857'
           });

```
        control.events.on({
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                //close existing popup
                if (popup) {
                    popup.destroy();
                }
                popup = new GeoExt.Popup({
                    title: "Feature Info",
                    map: mapPanel.map,
                    lonlat: mapPanel.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(event.xy),
                    width: 250,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    bodyStyle: {padding: 5},
                    location:event.xy,
                    html: event.text
                    });

                popup.show();
                }
        });

 mapPanel.map.addControl(control);
    control.activate();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over the geoserver and you use the html format, you could modify the [template](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/) server side. Otherwise I can think of retrieving the FeatureInfo as GML2 or text and modify if client-side. But I don't know how this might be implemented in openlayers.

Comment: please tell me how to modify  the template server side.

Comment: Have you read the link in my answer? Have a look at [custom templates](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/#custom-templates).

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of GeoServer you can also add the `propertyName` vendor option to the request and enumerate the attributes you want to include in the response:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#propertyname